# How load image as a react prop from the local directory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is the component I am trying to render which is being mapped over and the necessary props are being dropped in. One of those props are an image that is sitting in the local directory. When i type in that same `'..images/example.png'` it will load with out a problem. But when this data is being mapped over and the image directory is being dropped in as the `image` prop, it says that it cannot find the module. Any ideas why or what I can do to remedy this?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


class Project extends Component {


    render(){
        let {
            id,
            image
            } 
            = this.props
        return(
                <div className='project-container'>
                    <h1>{id}</h1>
                    <img src={require(image)} />
                    <p>description</p>
                    <p>technologies used</p>
                    <img src={require('../images/git.png')} />
                </div>

        )
    } 
}



export default Project;
```

Comment: Are you adding ../images/ before image? Like <img src={require(../images/+image)}?

Comment: yeah, my image prop is `image = '../images/dbz.png'` and i can see that it is accurate in reacts developer tools.

Comment: Try removing the path from the image prop and pass in just the name of the image. Then read the image in your display component like this <img alt=""  src={require('../images/'+image)} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} /> Make sure image prop has this value: 'git.png' and not the path.

Answer (score 1):

Your image prop shouldn't contain the path to image. But just the name of the image. Then you should read the image by doing something like

```
<img src={require('../images/'+image)}
```

Make sure the variable `image` just has the name of the actual image and not the path.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I can think of.

1. If you have created your React app using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), then there should be a folder called `public`.
   You need to put all your `static` assets (images, videos, mp3) in there.
2. If you have started from scratch (or from a boilerplate) using webpack, you need to import it (e.g. `import Git from './img/git.png'`) and configure the webpack to handle PNG or other types or image files.